# Oracle stored procedure not inserting data into table when successfully executed

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure which executes two insert statements successfully, however only the first insert query inserts into the table whereas the second one does not.

I execute my procedure with this command, only the the data for orders table inserts but no data is inserted into the order_item and I'm unsure why.

```
execute new_order(
    p_order_id => 4, 
    p_order_num => 'O223PS56',
    p_name => 'Test Test', 
    p_email => 'test@test.co.uk',
    p_address => '123 Test Street',
    p_city => 'Newcastle Upon Tyne',
    p_province => 'Tyne and Wear',
    p_postcode => 'NE98 4TN',
    p_telephone => '123456789',
    p_total => 7.97, p_order_date => to_date('11-apr-2021', 'DD-mon-YYYY'),
    p_order_item_id => 5, 
    p_product_id => 4, 
    p_seller_id => 2, 
    p_sub_order_number => 3073748221, 
    p_quantity => 2, 
    p_condition => 'Brand New', 
    p_unit_price => 1.99,
    p_cost_charge => 1.99);
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE new_order
-- define the variables for orders and order_item tables
(
    -- variables for the orders table
    p_order_id IN INT, 
    p_order_num IN CHAR,
    p_name IN CHAR, 
    p_email IN CHAR,
    p_address IN VARCHAR2,
    p_city IN VARCHAR2,
    p_province IN VARCHAR2,
    p_postcode IN VARCHAR2,
    p_telephone IN NUMBER,
    p_total IN NUMBER,
    p_order_date IN DATE,
    -- variables for the order_item table
    p_order_item_id IN INT,
    p_product_id IN INT,
    p_seller_id IN INT,
    p_sub_order_number IN CHAR,
    p_quantity IN INT,
    p_condition IN CHAR,
    p_unit_price IN NUMBER, 
    p_cost_charge IN NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert attempted');

    -- Insert data into the order table
    INSERT INTO orders(
        order_id, 
        order_number, 
        billing_name, 
        billing_email, 
        billing_address, 
        billing_city, 
        billing_province, 
        billing_postcode, 
        billing_telephone,
        billing_total,
        order_date)
    values(
        p_order_id, 
        p_order_num,
        p_name,
        p_email,
        p_address,
        p_city,
        p_province,
        p_postcode,
        p_telephone,
        p_total,
        p_order_date
        );

    COMMIT;

    -- Insert data into the order_item table
    INSERT INTO order_item(
        order_item_id,
        order_id,
        product_id,
        seller_id,
        sub_order_number,
        quantity,
        condition,
        unit_price,
        cost_charge
        )
    values(
        p_order_item_id,
        p_order_id,
        p_product_id,
        p_seller_id,
        p_sub_order_number,
        p_quantity,
        p_condition,
        p_unit_price,
        p_cost_charge
        );

    COMMIT;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert succeeded');

    EXCEPTION
     WHEN others THEN   
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert rejected');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SQL Error Code:  ' || SQLCODE);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SQL Error Message:  ' || SQLERRM); 
        ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

Console output

```
SQL> select * from orders;

  ORDER_ID ORDER_NUMB BILLING_NAME    BILLING_EMAIL   BILLING_ADDRESS      BILLING_CITY    BILLING_PROVINC BILLING_PO BILLING_TELEPHONE BILLING_TOTAL ORDER_DAT
---------- ---------- --------------- --------------- -------------------- --------------- --------------- ---------- ----------------- ------------- ---------
         1 O223PS56   Test Test       test@test.co.uk 123 Test Street      Newcastle Upon  Tyne and Wear   NE98 4TN           123456789          7.97 11-APR-21

SQL> select * from order_item;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Comment: what are the results shown on the console?

Comment: Remove the whole EXCEPTION section and try again. What is the result?

Comment: Observation: If an error occurs in the second insert, after you have committed the first, then the rollback in the exception will leave your data in an inconsistent state. Ideally you should only have a single `commit` after both inserts, or even better - issue the commit separately, outside of the procedure. That way if there is a rollback it will undo the *entire* transaction. There are other reasons - scalability, performance, etc. - not to use too many commits, too.

Comment: I've added the console output above, I did try one `commit` but neither queries inserted the data into the table

Comment: @Littlefoot removing the exeception helped me find the issue thanks. Also I've used a single commit in my procedure. Thank you all for the help

Comment: @Jal You should not use any `COMMIT` statements in the procedure then you can call multiple procedures and use `ROLLBACK` to reverse them all if and when needed. When you want to `COMMIT` the data then you should be doing it from the code that is calling the procedure.

Comment: What is the point of reporting the `sqlcode` separately? It's already part of `sqlerrm`. Also, why code `to_date('11-apr-2021', 'DD-mon-YYYY')` and not a normal date literal?